# How do you use ってこと

Tags: words, grammar

I heard in a podcast

> ってことは、たったままでねるってこと

I think it means something like "So that means you can sleep while standing?" but I'm not sure what the ってこと is doing here. The first one I get it's similar to つまり or am I wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「**ってことは**、たったままでねるってこと。」

「**って**ことは」 is an informal form of 「**という**ことは」. Other informal forms include 「**つう**ことは」、「**ちゅう**ことは」, etc.

When one of these expressions is used to **start a sentence**, its function is to rephrase and/or summarize what has already been stated.

It is synonymous to 「つまりは」 or 「結局{けっきょく}は」.  The English counterpart would be "***So that means ~~***" or "***That is to say ~~***"

> "So that means you/they/we/I sleep standing up."